# Why is necessary to have bind html input fields with ng-model directive to validate a form

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

I have a form like this

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input name="myEmail" type="email"/>

    {{myForm.$invalid}}
</form>
```

I need to bind my input field with ng-model to validate correctly the form. Why AngularJs is unable to validate this form just like this?

Even, the property *myForm.myEmail.$invalid* only exist if I bind the input with ng-model. Why is this so?

If validation only exist with ngModel directive, why angularjs give me the value *myForm.$invalid* to *false*? a better response would not be *undefined*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why AngularJs is unable to validate this form just like this?

Because validation makes sense only in context of ngModel directive, as this is what actually allows validation capabilities by registering corresponding model controller (ngModelController) with parent form directive controller, which orchestrates validation functionality.

Check the source to see how input directives are implemented and what they do with ngModel controller: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/71cf28cf06295e0936f706c048bc07e6c963acc4/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1708

Comment: Well said. To get a feel for what ngModel gives you, try this in your form (after adding `ng-model`, of course): `{{myForm.myEmail}}`. There are a lot of properties that don't exist on a normal input element without the `ng-model` directive.

Comment: If validation only exist with ngModel directive, why angularjs give me the value myForm.$invalid to false? a better response would not be undefined?

Comment: Because form controller has these properties ($invalid, $valid, $touched, etc.) initialized by default to some values: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/71cf28cf06295e0936f706c048bc07e6c963acc4/src/ng/directive/form.js#L76. But since there are no elements (with ngModel) registered within form there is that could change validation state of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Because angular validates the model, not the html. If you don't bind to a model, then, as far as angular is concerned, there's nothing to validate.